# React application is not auto-refreshing

Tags: reactjs

I am developing a React app using VS Code. Usually, when we make a change and save it, the browser should automatically refresh. However, my project is not behaving that way.

When I start the project using `npm start`, the console displays an error message: `Failed to compile`.

Additionally, it states

> ERROR in Module not found: Error: Can't resolve D:\oss\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\client\index.js?protocol=ws%3A&hostname=0.0.0.0&port=3000&pathname=%2Fws&logging=none&overlay=%7B%22errors%22%3Atrue%2C%22warnings%22%3Afalse%7D&reconnect=10&hot=true&live-reload=true' in 'D:\oss'.

However, my application is running, and it displays on the browser. The problem is that if I make a change, I have to manually refresh the browser to see the updated version.

To resolve this problem, I reinstalled NPM and changed the React versions. Can you guys help me to solve this problem :(

Comment: The dev-server will only load successfully compiled versions of the app, resolve your compilation error and you will get the live-updates back. Here's a question that seems potentially related to your error message and may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56870401/module-not-found-webpack-dev-server

Comment: Are you using `react-scripts`?

Comment: @DBS I followed your suggested answer, bull still have same issue.

Comment: @JoeLissner yes. Im using   "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },